# NTLM and Basic Auth Fails - API End Point Call

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to access a Web API using either Basic or NTLM authentication and keep getting an "Unauthorised" return response. The API running on an IIS server and both Basic and windows authentication is enabled.

My code that calls the API is below

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse> GetServiceResponse(string apiString, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var domain = _configuration.GetSection("RevBendSettings:Domain");
    var username = _configuration.GetSection("RevBendSettings:UserName");
    var password = _configuration.GetSection("RevBendSettings:Password");
    handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential($"{username.Value}", password.Value, $"{domain.Value}");
    var address = _httpClient.BaseAddress;

    _httpClient.BaseAddress = address;


    var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiString);

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceResponse));
    ServiceResponse servResp = (ServiceResponse)s.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(stream));

    return servResp;
}
```

Attached is also the response from the Server..
[image]